# Set the Edges Invisible [Feature-not-yet-supported]

Tags: modeling, edges

We have a mesh using the mirror modifier. How could we set the central edges (yellow arrow indicators pointing at) used for mirroring **invisible** during working on the mesh? Like in Lightwave or Nevercenter Silo 2.

The left is the original model, and the right is the wanted symmetrical line hidden model:

[image: illu]

This keeps the model looks neater when working on central parts of the model, like the nose:

[image: nose]

Comment: X - Dissolve edges?

Comment: No, we would like to hide these edges to make editing way neater; dissolving the edges will break the symmetry.

Comment: Okay you are going to have to explain how that makes editing 'way neater'.  What are the benefits of that?

Comment: Original post updated for explaination.

Comment: 'Neat' face topology is perfectly possible with a central edge loop.  E.g. https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/04/f5/6d/04f56d45b3dca2f1026ae1f514c59f84.jpg

Comment: In your example (and most of the example found on the web) there will be an symmetrical edge loop walking across the nose; mine doesn't. It's perfectly doable of course, just doesn't 'look' neat and kinda distracting when working on.

Comment: This won't be possible to achieve without applying Mirror mod and dissolving that edge. The main reason for this is that loops of the model flow in a way which assumes presence of one more near the mirror plane; you could redo that by grabbing whole mirrored part from mirrored plane and increase *Merge* threshold on Mirror mod, however this will enlarge the whole model.

Comment: It is possible as long as the edge owns a **visibility** attribute, so blender will know not-to-draw these edges if this visibility is preset to **false** by the user. Apparently blender doesn't have these kind of attributes defined for vertex/edge/face.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the Mirror modifier, with merge and clip enabled, then in Edit mode <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Right mouse button click on one of the edges to select loop, then  <kbd>X</kbd> and select Dissolve Edges from the pop up menu.

Comment: We would like to keep these edges (just hide them) to make editing way neater. Dissolve the edges will break the Symmetry.

Comment: You want to hide edges in Edit Mode?

Comment: Technically 'set them invisible'. in Blender 'hide' (H key) will also hide the face associated which is not what we want.

Answer (score 0):

My "solution" has been just to change the attitude about it. If I want to remove the middle seam I can easily do it once I apply the mirror modifier. However I find that having the middle seam there simply is beneficial to modeling, UV unwrapping, weight painting etc because often I want to give the middle vertices/edges special attention.

Comment: not removing them, but hiding them.